# Ionic unable to load App ID or API Key

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an existing app that I am trying to add push notifications to. After following through Ionic's own tutorials on adding it, I'm stuck with the app reporting:

```
CORE: Unable to load app ID or API key, falling back to $ionicApp.getApp()...
```

I've been Googling around trying to find an answer with no luck. In the main app.js I have added `ionic.service.core`, `ngCordova`, and `ionic.service.push`, as well as the config code block with the ids filled in:

```
.config(['$ionicAppProvider', function($ionicAppProvider) {
  $ionicAppProvider.identify({
    app_id: 'APP_ID',
    api_key: 'API_KEY'
  });
}])
```

In index.html I have added all the needed resources, particularly:

```
<script src="lib/ionic-service-core/ionic-core.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic-service-push/ionic-push.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
```

I have run `ionic config build`, `ionic prepare ios`, `ionic build ios`, `ionic config set dev_push true` repeatedly with no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do [these comments](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-service-core/issues/26) help? 'the default path is lib/ionic-service-core and lib/ionic add ionic-service-push. but my app structure is not like this [...]  I move them back to lib/ , warning is removed, and Android error is fixed'